# How to get a list of users who logged in after a certain date via YouTrack API?

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I need to get a list of users who logged in within the last 2 years. YouTrack Web interface shows me 141 users on /admin/hub/users?query=lastAccess(after:%202018-01-01)

But when I try to get the same list via API, I get an empty array. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my API request:

```
curl -X GET "https://[my_youtrack_URL]/api/admin/users?query=lastAccess(after:%202018-01-01)&$skip=0&$top=200"
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're missing an authentication token.
Try adding the following to your curl command `-H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken123"`. The token itself can be created in your [YouTrack user profile](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Manage-Permanent-Token.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not the case - I just didn't list the whole request. I have an auth token and all other headers, and some other requests I make work well. It's something in the query syntax of this particular one.

Comment: I see. Then it must be the wrong API endpoint you refer to. Give `https://[my_youtrack_URL]/hub/api/rest/users` a try.

Comment: you're right, but that appeared to be only one half of the answer. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the YouTrack developers, it's two-fold:

1) First, the endpoint for request concerning users is different - this is a "hub" feature, so the endpoint should be `/hub/api/rest/users` (as also mentioned by @Jk1 above).

2) Second, the correct syntax for the query is `lastAccess(after:+2018-01-01)` (`+` instead of `%20`).